# How to collapse JSON code where only the first tag is displayed?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

How can I collapse JSON code and see only the first tag, similar to how WebStorm does it?

[image: image copied from https://screencast.com/t/7ej35eRx]

I am looking for this in VS Code / Sublime settings or plugin but I can't find them.

Comment: Please post your code with proper formatting. Posting an image is not recommended, because you make it hard on anyone who wants to answer the question. (No copy-paste from images).

Answer (score 1):

VS code already does that, just change the file type at the bottom left.

[image]

Comment: thank's but is not that, is collapsing code but first line still visible with first value. When you collapse in vs code only can see the {}, is not readable with big json files

Answer (score -5):

try to write like this code below:

```
[{
        "name": "saphria",
        "model": "Honda",
    },
    {
        "name": "massi",
        "model": "Mercedes",

    }

]
```

Comment: The question was about **visually** collapsing JSON **using the IDE**.